# How to consume rest apis more than one with django?

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I want to get data from multiple api in django using `request.get()` method. Normally we fetched data like this:

```
response = requests.get('http://freegeoip.net/json/')
```

Is it possible  to get data from 3 different api like this.

```
response=requests.get('http://freegeoip.net/json/','http://api.example.com','http://api.anotherexample.com');
```

Comment: That's very specific, I think, to your application. The way you combine the results from the three different services may differ from any body else. Furthermore there's nothing wrong with implementing it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of url and **iterate** over your urls.

**Ex:**

```
urlList = ['http://freegeoip.net/json/','http://api.example.com','http://api.anotherexample.com']
result = []
for url in urlList:
    result.append(requests.get(url))
print(result)
```

Comment: You're getting only the last response.

Comment: If you want to store the response you can append it to a list

Answer (score 0):

Simplest answer is NO because python request module is generic function; even if you implement 3 urls to same or different server you must request for it separately hence if it's 3 request you must request for three times; the reason it should not be combined it for error detection. you can not handle or know which url cause error so that you didn't get your response.

```
url_set = ['http://freegeoip.net/json/','http://api.example.com','http://api.anotherexample.com']
response_set = {}  # maintain dict to store responsese
for url in url_set:
    response_set[url] = request.get(url)
```

So now you can access all the response of respective urls also if you are getting any kind of error for particular url you can handle it though you might face many different cases for it like request timeout, SSL certificate warning etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be a bit fancy and save some memory, use generator:

```
def get_responses(*urls, **kwargs):
    for url in urls:
        yield requests.get(url, **kwargs)

urls = ['http://freegeoip.net/json/','http://api.example.com','http://api.anotherexample.com']

for response in get_responses(*urls):
    # do something to the response
```

Comment: You can also use it like this: `get_responses('http://freegeoip.net/json/','http://api.example.com','http://api.anotherexample.com')`